# PySimpleGUI icons cross-platform support

Tags: python, user-interface, cross-platform, pysimplegui

I was wondering if there was a way to make a PySimpleGUI application have an icon (the icon you use to switch apps at the bottom of the screen) that works on Windows and MacOS. I know that Windows needs ico and MacOS need icns, so, is there a way to include both and have it switch to the right one depending on the OS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An example of a platform-dependent assignment:

```py
import platform

icon = icon1 if platform.system() == 'Windows' else icon2
```

BTW we use the same .ico file for both Windows and MacOS.